# softlinks atime and mtime modification

Tags: c, linux, command-line, symlink

Is it possible to change the `atime` and `mtime` of a symlink?

I am trying to change it using the `utime()` function(C code) but instead it changes the time of destination files.

Also if I do

```
cp -dpr <src fldr> <<dest folder> (command line)
```

[The src folder contains different symlinks.]
the symlinks at destination are created with current timestamp.

Doing a `stat()` on the symlink will give me the timing of destination file (in C code) but if we fire a `stat` command on command line it gives the timestamp of link(possibly it is using `lstat`)

Any ideas?

Comment: With respect to both my and @PaulP.R.O's answers, do you use a shell or developing a program?

Comment: am trying both, but my primary intention is to develop a c code for it.

Comment: It's still not been resolved :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can use touch with the `-h` flag in bash to modify the mtime and atime of the symlink instead of the file it references:

```
touch -h somesymlink
```

You can use the `-t` flag to specify a time to set it to, if you don't want to use the current time.

Comment: -h option dint worked at my end...  i tried using -t option instead it sets the timestamp of destination file not of symlink...

Answer (score 1):

Use `lutimes` instead. See `man lutimes` or http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Times.html