# Set atime and mtime of a symlink with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, symlink

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119242/softlinks-atime-and-mtime-modification), but with Node in a cross-platform way.

[`fs.utimes`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_utimes_path_atime_mtime_callback) seems to set the target file instead of the symlink itself. All I could find is [this old open issue about adding lutimes](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2142).

Comment: Since the issue hasn't been implemented, you still can't do it.

Comment: You could execute the `touch` shell command with the `-h` option.